# Reguar expression to allow few Special Characters

Tags: regex, validation

I am new to Validation through RegEx

I want to Validate an input field through regex that

Must have Alphanumeric Characters
Must contain - _ / . ( )

Comment: What have you tried? And it is always a good idea to tell what kind of regex (dialect) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your regex will define a set (you need to escape some special characters with `\`):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\.\(\)]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the job:

```
^[\w/.()-]+$
```

`\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

For alpha numeric characters (assuming English characters), you can use the following: `^[A-Za-z0-9_\/.()-]+$`.

Please take a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) tutorial for more information and [here](http://regex101.com/r/rE1rM7) for a more detailed explanation of the regex.